# How to fix: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I created an **ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)** with .NET Framework 4.7 and with ASP.NET Web Forms template and authentication mode *Individual User Accounts*.

**My connection string**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=mysql server;password=password;port=3306;uid=username;database=schemaname" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

*(It's filled with CORRECT values, but I don't want to publish them...)*
**Entity Framework**

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

**Error**

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The Entity Framework provider type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6'
>   registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider
>   with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make
>   sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is
>   available to the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'

**at**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
     public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)//<-- this line
     {
     }

     public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
     {
         return new ApplicationDbContext();
     }
}
```

**I already read those:**

- [Exception : The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string-Entityframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279019/exception-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string-entityfra)
- [The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532750/the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string)
- [The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269682/the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string-error)
- [Dynamic MySQL database connection for Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277677/dynamic-mysql-database-connection-for-entity-framework-6)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

When I fixed an error another appeared after fixing than appeared another and so on, so I created a new project with settings above and I hope someone can help me to solve this issue. (This is my first time using ASP.NET Web Forms)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to be using MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.7. I'm going to guess you're also using MySql.Data 8.0.11.

These two libraries are not compatible. Oracle [renamed the package](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,661134) to [`MySql.Data.EntityFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/) for v8.x. You need to uninstall `MySql.Data.Entity` and install `MySql.Data.EntityFramework`.